# How to pass variables in .env file to angular6 environment.ts file

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

With `angular6`, the global variable `process` is undefined.

I dockerlize my angular app using `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`

I create `.env` file store my secret variables used by `docker-compose.yml`

But, if I get the variables stored in `.env` file in application code like this:

`process.env.GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN`

An error will be thrown

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(41,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.
src/app/app.module.ts(53,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.
```

My requirements are:

1. run application in docker container using `docker-compose up`
2. Within application code, get the environment variables which are defined in `.env` file.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  angular-apollo-starter:
    image: angular-apollo-starter
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

I think pass environment variables workflow should be like this:

`.env` -> `environment.prod.ts` -> `application code`

**update**

I found an issue about this problem: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4318

Comment: have you tried like `./.env` ?

Comment: And your build process is before deploying on docker right?

Comment: You could try retrieving settings at runtime from a json file located in the assets folder (instead of directly using environment.ts). That json config file would contain placeholders that'd be replaced with en variables when you start your CMD process

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script and execute it before build with something like *prebuild*. In that script you have access to *process* and you can replace some values in environment.ts with what you need.