# Angular 6, should I put secret environment variables in environment.ts file?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

There are two sub-questions:

1. Should I put secret environment variables in the `environment.ts` file?
2. The `process` variable shim is gone. If I use it, `tsc` will throw an error: `Cannot find name 'process'`.

Here is my thing:

About Q1: I don't think put secret environment variables in environment.ts file is correct. Because these files will be a push to source code management, like GitHub, GitLab, bitbucket. It's not safe. So I think secret environment variables should be passed through `process.env`, like `process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN`, or, if use docker-compose, should put the secret environment variables in `.env` file and add this file to `.gitignore` file.

About Q2: If I use Heroku to set up my environment variables, it depends on the `process` variable. Now, angular6 get rid of the shim of `process`, How can I work with Heroku? Also, using docker-compose pass environment variables through `.env` file depends on `process` too.

And if use `.env` file for docker-compose, there is a new question come out: [How to pass variables in .env file to angular6 environment.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355142/how-to-pass-variables-in-env-file-to-angular6-environment-ts-file)

**update 1:**

Here is a case:

First, **there is no back-end**

I use GitHub API and another open API, and there is an environment variable named `access_token`,
If I put this in the `environment.ts` file and push my front-end source code to Github, Github will detect the secret information and give me a warning, they say:

> You should not put the GitHub access token in your source code and push it to repo, so they will revoke my access token.

So I want to use `process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN`, but the `process` variable shim is gone in `Angular6`, how can I solve this? Should I add `environment.ts` file to the `.gitignore` file or what?

**update 2**

Here is another case

Continue with update 1. Now, I add `docker-compose.yaml` and `Dockerfile` to run my front-end app in the `docker` container.

Here is the workflow:

1. Write `Dockerfile`, run `npm run build` command and copy `./build` directory to `nginx` static file directory of `docker` container. the `./build` directory contains `index.html`, `bundle.js` file and so on.
2. Put `access_token` and other secret environment variables into `.env` file.
3. Run `docker-compose up` to run my app in a `docker` container.

I think this workflow is solid. No need back-end service, the secret environment variables in `.env` and `.gitignore` contains `.env` file, so it will not be pushed to Github repo.

But, the key point is `process` shim is gone. I can't get environment variables through `process`.

**update 3**

I think my question focus on **front-end app development phase**.
I continue to use above case to explain.

For production ready, the workflow is:

1. Make a back-end service for github oauth, when the oauth workflow is done. Back-end service send `access_token` to front-end.
2. front-end login successfully, get the `access_token` from back-end service and store it in localStorage or cookie. Don't need get `access_token` from `process.env`

But for development phase, Front-end and back-end development are separated for the general situation. So, Front-end should not depend on the back-end service.

And I don't want to build the whole big system for the beginning.

So I think the question is:

Where to store secret environment variables and how to get within `Angular6` front-end application code? Several situations need to be considered:

- Work with PaaS Heroku config vars
- Dockerized(docker-compose, Dockerfile), `.env` file.
- Without back-end service.
- Add the environment variables file to `.gitignore`, don't push  to SCM(Github, GitLab and so on)

Comment: Is your website designed to be public? Should access token be public information? If yes, then build it into the JS code; otherwise hide it in a back-end server. You can hide nothing in front end.

Comment: Putting sensitive data in the source code is not a good idea at all (for a security measure), take a look on how to set external env variables https://smaillns.medium.com/handling-environment-variables-in-angular-application-125083e905f6

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**TL; DR**

You should not treat `environment.ts` as something similar to `process.env`.

The name is similar but the behaviour is absolutely not. All the settings from `environment.ts` will directly go to your code. That's why it is not secure to put secrets to `environments.ts` in any way.

The browser alternatives to environment variables (`process.env`) are

- sessionStorage: behaves like `export VAR=value`
- localStorage: behaves like `export VAR=value` but put into your `.bash_profile` and is persistent across sessions
- indexedDB: same as localStorage with only difference its **asynchronous**
- cookies: does not really look like `process.env`, but still in some cases can send the secrets automatically to some backends
- backend: it is always an option to get secrets from backend, **asynchronous**

**Long version**

There is no such a thing as a secret in the client side application. Since your code in the browser will be able to get those variables, everybody will be able to get those variables in the runtime.

That means, all libraries you explicitly or implicitly use, user's browser extensions and anybody who is able to sniff your / your user's traffic - all they will get your secrets quite easily.

It does not matter how you pass it. Through process.env or environment.ts, all will end up in the generated main.js file where they are so much not secret anymore that the furhter discussion is actually useless.

**Answer to updated part 1:**

If `access_token` is your (or your synthetic user) token, then you have two options:

1. Write a backend service that pushes the code on behalf of this Github user. That means the token will be stored in the environment variable on a backend side, which is a very much appropriate way of doing stuff
2. Ask your user to enter the token for every push or ask it once and store it in a localStorage. This make sense only in case when every user has its own / different token

**Answer to updated part 2:**

You can build a docker around your frontend, run it within a kubernetes cluster inside a virtual machine which is hosted on the most secure server in the world, it will not make your token secure if you put it as angular environment variable because what is public cannot be secret.

You seem to be not understanding the main point: GitHub gives you an error and does not allow to push the code, you should already be grateful that it finds a problem in your architecture. If you want to solve the problem then use the solutions above. If you want to simply bypass the validation of GitHub and you don't care about the security then simply split your token string into two pieces and store it apart and GitHub will not be able to find it.

**Answer to updated part 3:**

You can perform GitHub's Oauth2 requests directly from your frontend. Every of your users should have an account there and that would solve all your problems. That's actually the same what was proposed as a solution #2.

If you go with solution #1 with a backend, for development purposes just pre-set up the cookie or use `localStorage.setItem('your-token-here')`. This is way more than enough for development purposes.

Comment: yeah, I know this, no matter through `process.env` or `environment.ts` , after compile and build, the final bundle.js file will contain every environment variables at runtime, even the secret environment variables.

Comment: Then they are not secret. That’s the point. You can store them in git or show it to the user in a pop up right away - it is nearly the same level of security. Front end code is not a place for any secret variable.

Comment: Reply `Answer to updated part 2:`, Oh no, I just want to develop an Angular 6 front-end app. Kubernetes, docker-machine...These things are production ready things. That adds too many things. Just for developing an `Angular 6` front-end? NO!  Even perform GitHub's Oauth2 requests directly from your frontend, that's too heavy either. Like I said, I don't want to build a whole big system at beginning. Just for secret environment variables? NO!  The last advice is simple and good enough. Store my `access_token` to localStorage directly.

Comment: the kubernetes thing was sarcasm :) Please check the updated top of the answer. I think that's the main thing we discuss

Comment: looks like the only solution is having a backend?

I am on the same boat. I have a tool that makes api call to bitbucket and jira. Currently I am hardcoding username/password in the code but I want to move it to .env...the tool will not need to ask for login and it will use my read only credentials...