# CONFIG Problem for Firebase Authentication In IONIC (Angular) Project

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I made an IONIC project which can be authenticated with Facebook and Google and i put config file(in the picture) in the `app.module.ts`

[image: Firebase Config For IONIC Angular]

**Is `app.module.ts` only seen by the developer?**

- Can user see this config file when user makes apk to code this project ?
- Is this a bug that i made ? Do i have to make API for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can all be made public (client-side).  This is intended for client configurations.  If you look under the `web` section in the Firebase console you'll see that they tell developers to paste that in their client-side (JavaScript SDK) code.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [**Installation and Setup guide**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md#1-installation-and-setup) for [**`@angular/fire`**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), they keep it in the `/src/environments/environment.ts`. I'm not sure if that's the recommended place to keep any front-end configurations in the App.

People have mixed opinions about it. You might want to read through [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51490031/2622292) to know more.

I think making an API call would make it more prone to sniff and hack. Someone could see your Network Requests and get a hold of the response payload for that matter.

### UPDATE:

No, it's **NOT SAFE** to keep Firebase Config in environment.ts or environment.prod.ts.

As of now, AngularCLI only minifies the code. If you open up Devtools on your Browser, select `main.hash-code-for-the-bundle.js` and pretty print it, and then try to find by something like `messagingSenderId`, you'll be able to see it.

[image]

**NOTE:** This is a real production app.

Comment: how did you solve storing the secret in a safe matter? thanks for the tip