# How to hide API Keys with Angular 8/9?

Tags: firebase, environment-variables, angular8

I'm trying to call the Firebase API. To call this API, we need to specify a user config key. How can I hide this key in my code? I have no idea how to do.

If I use the environment.ts file, after build, those keys are exposing in the main.js file.

**main.js**
[Keys Exposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fRDl.png)

Is there any way to avoid the exposure of these keys in main.js file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6, should I put secret environment variables in environment.ts file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489904/angular-6-should-i-put-secret-environment-variables-in-environment-ts-file)

Comment: You can't the Firebase configuration data - it is public information needed by your client app to access Firebase.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase is designed such a way that you do not have to hide these keys.

Please refer to doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys) and extract below:

> Unlike how API keys are typically used, API keys for Firebase services are not used to control access to backend resources; that can only be done with Firebase Security Rules. Usually, you need to fastidiously guard API keys (for example, by using a vault service or setting the keys as environment variables); however, API keys for Firebase services are ok to include in code or checked-in config files.